# What are the reference epoch dates (and times) for various platforms and languages?

Tags: datetime

Time is often converted into numeric parameter (e.g., to miliseconds or other units) elapsed from a reference date (epoch time)
The overview on wikipedia is very incomplete:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29

What is is the list of epoch times for all possible OS platforms and major programming languages?

(e.g., R (running on different OS platforms,unix, windows, Android, Apple, Perl, Python, Ruby, C++, Java).

Answer (score 1):

In most modern frameworks,  it's the [Unix/POSIX standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) of 1/1/1970.

You asked about R - it's 1/1/1970.  [Refrence Here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html)

Most languages/frameworks that are cross platform either do this internally, or they abstract it.  It would be too painful otherwise.  Imagine having to compensate for a different epoch every time you re-targeted.  That would be aweful.

BTW - There is another list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_time) that may be more interesting to you.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the following data:

`In a computing context, an epoch is the date and time relative to which a computer's clock and timestamp values are determined. The epoch traditionally corresponds to 0 hours, 0 minutes, and 0 seconds (00:00:00) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) on a specific date, which varies from system to system. Most versions of Unix, for example, use January 1, 1970 as the epoch date; Windows uses January 1, 1601; Macintosh systems use January 1, 1904, and Digital Equipment Corporation's Virtual Memory System (VMS) uses November 17, 1858.`

Reference : [Epoch](http://searchdatacenter.techtarget.com/definition/epoch)

also you can see this : [Epoch Computer](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/e/epoch.htm)

In Java epoch is like unix i.e. January 1 1970 Midnight which is used in programming widely.

Comment: Note, Win32 uses 1601 for historical reasons.  .Net uses 1970 like most everyone else.