# C++ on Visual Studio 2022 last_write_time returns huge number

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, c++20

I am writing a simple c++20 program to get the last modified time of a file. On MacOS it works fine and returns the Unix Epoch Time in Seconds for a file modified just yesterday. However, on Windows with Visual Studio 2022, the code below returns `Got Modified Time of: 13314844775` which, according the Unix Time Stamp Tool here is 369 years in the future. How can this be properly converted?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::string fileName = "test.txt";    
    
    auto modTime = std::filesystem::last_write_time(std::filesystem::path(fileName));
    auto epoch = modTime.time_since_epoch();
    auto converted = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(epoch);
    auto counts = converted.count();    
    std::cout << "Got Modified Time of: " << counts << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The Windows epoch is January 1, 1601. [What are the reference epoch dates (and times) for various platforms and languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027010/what-are-the-reference-epoch-dates-and-times-for-various-platforms-and-languag)

Comment: @RaymondChen Sad to see this item closed because the said duplicate has no concrete question or code. As of today, there are very few examples of `clock_cast` and it is not clear this is the best way because the current Xcode release doesn't even appear to fully support it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return value of `last_write_time` is a `time_point` which uses the `file_clock` clock to base its time on. This clock may *or may not* have the same epoch as any other clock. The epoch is implementation-defined.

As such, the behavior of your code changes with the implementation.

If you want to get a file's time with respect to UNIX time, you need C++20, which added the `clock_cast` functionality. This allows you to convert a time point into one relative to a different clock. So you would do this:

```
auto modTime = std::filesystem::last_write_time(std::filesystem::path(fileName));
auto modTimeUnix = std::chrono::clock_cast<std::chrono::system_clock>(modTime);
```

In C++20, `system_clock` is required to be in UNIX time across all implementations, and `file_clock` is required to be able to be converted into `system_clock`.